# Custom about dialogs in Eclipse applications

Tags: java, eclipse

I have an Eclipse workbench application composed of many plugins. I'd like to set the about text of the app to reflect the build number.

There seems to be a couple of places to do this: 
 - Inside the application's .product file (setting text here doesn't seem to do anything?)
 - Inside the plugin.xml file of the main plugin (this does seem to work).

I have two questions:

1. What is the best way to achieve this? via plugin.xml?
2. Why is the text I set in the product file ignored?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It (text and picture of an about dialog) should be in the [about.ini](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ecfeat/index.html) of a [feature](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Update/index.html) or product plugin.

[image: Branding, after www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ecfeat/branding.jpg]

Note: for the picture, this blog entry "[How Can I Give My Eclipse Blob An Icon In The Flippin’ About Dialog?](http://pookzilla.net/wp/2006/01/how-can-i-give-my-eclipse-blob-icon-in/)" is quite nice.

Notebis: with the latest 3.5Mx releases, the [about box is even more configurable](http://blog.eclipse-tips.com/2009/02/customizing-about-dialog.html).

Comment: Nice post! Thank you. I think I'll have to revise our approach to branding to something more Feature oriented.
Any ideas why the various plugins/products have spots for setting about info as well? Is there any use for these fields?